# pseudo-elementos y less en un mixin (De Sass a Less)

Tags: css3, sass, scss, less

Estoy intentando crear un mixin, el cual le paso el parámetro de la posición del pseudo-elemento.
El por qué viene de que estoy intentando traducir un mixin de scss en el que en función de la posición, a la clase donde le apliques dicho mixin le pones un ::after o un ::before:

La clase en scss:

```
@mixin selectPosition($position: before){
    &::#{$position}{ //por defecto coge el before
        //css properties
    }
}
```

Y mi intento de traducción a less:

```
.selectPosition(@position: before){
    &::@{position}{
        //css properties
    }
}
```

¿Cómo sería la traducción correcta?

Comment: es correcta tu solución. Cual es el problema?

Comment: @hawks si lo compilo en un compilador online, me salta error...

Answer (score 0):

Si te vas a [esta herramienta online](https://www.cssportal.com/less-to-css/) para compilar `LESS` a `CSS` verás que se compila bien.

Tienes que poner alguna propiedad para que te funcione bien.

En el apartado de LESS pones esto y le das a compilar y veras que lo hace bien.

```css
.selectPosition(@position: before){
    &::@{position}{
        //css properties
        content: '';
    }
}

.container {
    .selectPosition();
}
```

**EDIT**

Creo que la [página](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/) que has puesto no contempla bien el selector de los pseudo-elementos. Si pones `:` en vez de `::` compila correctamente.

```
.selectPosition(@position: before){
  &:@{position}{  
    content: "";
  }
}

.container {
  .selectPosition();
}
```

Comment: Pero si lo pruebas en esta otra no: http://lesscss.org/less-preview/

Comment: quizá falla su implementación de less a css. Para salir de dudas mejor hazlo en tu local y así sabrás si va o no.

Comment: @MrRobot he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Aún no he compilado en vscode, pero me marca error cuando concateno : con el parámetro